# How should I format the HTML of my blog posts in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, blog, html

For convenience, I write all my blog posts in bare HTML. Everything seems to be working, but I see that sometimes, Blogger's WYSIWYG editor wraps everything up in a `<div>` and uses `<p>` tags. Should I use those? I usually just type in raw text and use double `<br>` tags to differentiate between paragraphs. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Depends on if you want line breaks or paragraphs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use `br` elements for separating paragraphs. From the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-br-element.html#the-br-element):

> `br` elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses.

A paragraph should be enclosed in a `p` element.

The `div` element doesn't add/change any meaning. At most it changes the styling of the content (via CSS; depends on the theme). So you can omit it if you are happy with the design of your content.